# Java Regex : Regex with "|" (Vertical bar or pipe) not working properly. Need a help to split a string by comma

Tags: java, regex

```
Example 1:
Input String : String1, {String2,String3},String4,[String5,String6]
Regex to Split : ",(?!([^{[]*[\]}]))"
Output : 
[0] String1
[1] {String2,String3}
[2] String4
[3] [String5,String6]
```

Demo : https://regex101.com/r/MUIA2J/1

But instead of square brackets if we have double quotes characters or vertical bar/pipe chars, then it doesn't work.
Like explained below

```
Example 2:
Input String : String1, {String2,String3},String4,|String5,String6|
Regex to Split : ",(?!([^{|]*[\|}]))"
Output : 
[0] String1
[1] {String2,String3},String4,|String5,String6|
```

Why is that? How to achieve modify the regex in example-2 to get similar output as example-1?

Comment: Right, the problem is that the common workaround like the one you are using is not suitable when the leading and trailing delimiters are identical. You should match with `\{[^{}]*}|\|[^|]*\||[^{}|\s,]+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMNHtl/1))

Comment: The split variant could be `,(?=[^{}]*(?:\{[^{}]*})*[^{}]*$)(?=[^|]*(?:\|[^|]*\|)*[^|]*$)(?=[^]\[]*(?:\[[^]\[]*])*[^]\[]*$)` but matching would be a better option I think https://regex101.com/r/YpxJbn/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```java
\{[^{}]*}|\|[^|]*\||[^{}|\s,]+
```

to collect the matched substrings into a resulting list. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vMNHtl/3).

*Details*:

- `\{[^{}]*}` -  `{`, any zero or more chars other than a `{` and `}` chars and then a `}`char
- `|` - or
- `\|[^|]*\|` - `|`, any zero or more chars other than a `|` char and then a `|`char
- `|` - or
- `[^{}|\s,]+` - one or more chars other than `{`, `}`, `|` and whitespace

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/kUpi2Z):

```java
String text = "String1, {String2,String3},String4,|String5,String6|";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\{[^{}]*}|\\|[^|]*\\||[^{}|\\s,]+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // Just printing for demo
    res.add(m.group());            // Collecting into a list of strings
}
# => String1
# => {String2,String3}
# => String4
# => |String5,String6|
```

Comment: Works perfectly. But need to test with more samples. Thank you @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: Thank you @The fourth bird for your suggestion as well. But I have not tested your regex yet. I think it's too complicated to read & understand.